# Speech Recognition and Text to Speech

Tags: c#, chatbot

Hi my chatbot implementation has an issue where the input (mic) recognises the computer output (speaker). What are some workarounds you guys have put in place? One logic I can think of is just to have the recognition execute every other count of a loop. Thanks.